# Axon - Custom Message Bus

Tags: axon

Do any of you use Axon framework with custom bus instead of Axon server?

I would like to use Axon framework with custom message bus. Unfortunately I could not see anything in their documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by a custom message bus? Can you elaborate a bit more what you are trying to achieve? I am asking that because Axon has several extensions for example `amqp`, `kafka`, etc and those can be used as a Message Bus if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @RamPrakash you can find the documentation about the distributed command bus here:  https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/infrastructure#the-command-bus-distributed and about the event store here: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-bus-and-event-store

Comment: The link is broken. Second I am looking for custom bus configuration example.

Comment: I updated the link and added another one. Is the DistributedEventBus and the JpaEventStorageEngine what you are looking for?